# Java MouseEntered is referring to entering which component?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

In Java mouseListener, one of the methods is `mouseEntered()`.

According to the `API` it says:

> Invoked when the mouse enters a component.

**So my question is:** Which component is the API referring to? Is it the component which adds the mouseListener?

**Example:**

```
JLabel labelA = new JLabel();
JLabel labelB = new JLabel();
labelA.addMouseListener(new LabelMouseListener());
//Codes for LabelMouseListener class not shown
```

So mouseEntered in the above case only works when I move my mouse cursor into the area of `labelA`. Am I right?

### NOTE: I have already tested it, and it WORKS on labelA only. BUT I want to confirm whether the API is solely referring to the compoenent which add the listener.

**My 2nd Question:** If I have a JComponent which class implements mouseListener, when will the mouseEntered/Exited be triggered in this class?

Is it when I move my mouse cursor in/out of this JComponent?

**Example:**

```
class myDisplay extends JComponent implements mouseListener
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you need confirmation? What is happening that you don't expect?

Comment: You actually can be sure what the API is referring to just by looking at the result. The documentation itself should be enough to know what the function/type does. If you test it and it works, then you can be sure

Comment: @user3437460, Sorry, I don't understand your confusion, you seem to be making things too complicated. When you invoke setText() on labelA, can you be sure that it doesn't update the text on labelB? If you only add the MouseListener to labelA how will an event be generated on labelB? This would be very confusing if your programs started responding to events even if you didn't add a listener to the component.

Comment: `"BUT I want to confirm whether the API is solely referring to the compoenent which add the listener."` -- what else would it be listening to? How would it even know about any other components that may or may not be present?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I ask that because I tested one of the example from Oracle site. The mouseEntered is not only triggered when I mouseExit /enter the panel (which adds the listener). It also works on other component which didn't directly add the mouse Listener.

Comment: @user3437460: What example do you refer to? What behaviors confused you? Do you have a link?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This is the link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html You will be able to launch the program and see the codes there. The listener is  added on the panel, but as you move the mouse over the yellow portion of the GUI, mouseEntered/Exited gets triggered as well.

Comment: Then you should look at the source code first: it shows that it adds a MouseMotionListener to multiple components! `blankArea.addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thank you for looking into the codes but `e.getComponent().getClass().getName()` actually gives different component names. And this is from `e` which is the component generating the event. I know from the start it is listening to one component, but are other components took part in it when did not add the listener? This is why even I tested my own codes, I still ask a question here. I asked after numerous research and testing. But still get down voted by the assumptious camickr.
`

Comment: `"...actually gives different component names"` -- because multiple components are listened to!

Answer (score 5):

The documentation states:

> The listener object created from that class is then **registered with a component** *using the component's addMouseListener method*. A mouse event is generated when the mouse is pressed, released clicked (pressed and released). A mouse event is also generated *when the mouse cursor enters or leaves a component.*

I guess they could have replaced ***a component*** with ***the component*** for the last statement. Either way, testing it would confirm your beliefs.

To sum it up...

Yes, it's referring to the component the listener is added to.

For the second question, even if you implement `MouseListener`, you'll still need to add it to that component:

```
class MyClass extends JComponent implements MouseListener {

    public MyClass() {
         addMouseListener(this); //adds this instance's listener to this component
    }

    //override methods
}
```

And yes, it'll only trigger when your mouse enters/exits this component (only if you remember to add the listener, though; it wont work just because it's implemented, you MUST add it as well)

Comment: I can discuss with you on with chat. How do we move there?

Comment: @user3437460 As Hovercraft said, it's best to answer your questions here where everyone can learn from it. If you have *that* many questions, they should probably be asked in separate posts. Also, make sure to look online for examples and to make sure your question hasn't already been asked and answered